# What is this System.ArgumentException on ContainerBuilder.Build (autofac)? And is it a problem?

Tags: c#, autofac, .net-4.8

When running the following code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Build();
```

with Exception Settings: (all) Common Language Runtime Errors, I get the following error

System.ArgumentException: 'Bit position in AllKeywords (48) must equal the command argument named "EtwSessionKeyword" (43).'

What is this System.ArgumentException on ContainerBuilder.Build? And is it a problem?

I am running in .Net 4.8, Autofac 6.5.0

Comment: You should include the complete stack trace with the exception, not just the message. Probably also good to include what kind of project it is (console app, library, etc.).

Comment: @TravisIllig unfortunately I have the same problem too and the stack trace is

   at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.DoCommand(EventCommandEventArgs commandArgs)

The call that fails is the new ContainerBuilder()